# Rails firebird error expression evaluation not supported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebird2.5, activerecord-fb-adapter

I'm getting the following error during migration, i've searched the web and no one seem to encounter this, so any help would be appreciated.

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Fb::Error: expression evaluation not supported
value exceeds the range for valid timestamps

Thanks

Comment: What migration causes this? What is the data that is causing the problem?

Comment: Actually I am testing the migration using a Vagrant box but with using the same versions of rails, ruby and firebird and it's working fine. I'm getting this when using a live server which is why this is weird.